# Scroll to top and bottom using pure javascript with time

Tags: javascript

I have a scrollable `div`, I want to scroll to its bottom, and then after reaching bottom, it should scroll to top with given time.

I was able to achieve it, but time is not working, scrolling happens very quick. Here is my code.

```
var done = 0;

var scrollablediv = document.querySelectorAll(".chatlist-panel-body")[0];
divheight = scrollablediv.scrollHeight;
scrollTo(scrollablediv,divheight,2000);

function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
    if (duration <= 0) return;
    var difference = to - element.scrollHeight;
    var perTick = difference / duration * 10;

    setTimeout(function() {
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight + perTick;
        console.log(element.scrollHeight);
        if (element.scrollHeight === to)
        { 
            console.log("done");
            if(!done)
            {
                done = 1;
                scrollTo(scrollablediv,0,2000); 
            }
            return;
        }
        scrollTo(element, to, duration - 10);
    }, 10);
}
```

Comment: You always use 10 milliseconds in setTimeout disregarding your duration param

Comment: yes it checks every10 milli seconds and scroll slow by slow